# How to get name of property field of SPSS objects

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

Hi I'm new to SPSS scripting. I'm using IBM SPSS Modeler 17.1. I need to understand how to refer the property field name in SPSS. For example, I'm using distribution object under graph & for setting the color property of the object I'm using fieldname as `"color_field"` and code I'm using is `node.setPropertyValue("color_field","Drug")` By opening the object in SPSS Modeler window I can see a property named as `Selected field`. I want to use that property. Is there any way in SPSS modeler so that I can get the name of the property field in my SPSS script by visually seeing the property in Modeler Window?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the available properties for each node in the [Scripting and Automation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.0.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita-gentopic5.html) section of the Modeler Help.
There is section that is specific to the [Distribution node](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.0.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/distributionnodeslots.html), which lists the properties that are specific to that node.

There is no resource that directly connects the selections in the user interface with the node slots, but the naming is pretty self-explanatory for the most part (but not always).